# Is it possible that an LCD monitor gets pixels damaged in transit?

Tags: dead-pixel

Is it possible that an LCD monitor gets pixels damaged in transit?

I bought a used LCD monitor without testing it first, and when I got home I found it had three  contiguous stuck pixels on its screen (they're pink when screen is black, disappears when screen is white) . There are no visible physical damage on the device.  However, the seller is claiming the damage wasn't there when he last checked it.

I spent hours last night trying the software, pressure, tapping and heat [repair methods](http://www.wikihow.com/Fix-a-Stuck-Pixel-on-an-LCD-Monitor) to no avail.

Is it even possible that the dead pixels happened in transit, while carrying it home?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experience, yes, it is possible. Especially if anything comes in contact with the screen in a harsh manner. Sometimes when people carry their monitor they wrap the power cord and/or video cable around the monitor. If these accidentally hit the screen it can sometimes cause dead pixels. This could have been pressure from something setting against the screen like a zipper, or hard cuff of a jacket and not necessarily just by hitting it hard.

Sounds like you've done a good job troubleshooting itUnfortunatelyyt, you've probably already realized it, but you should have checked it before you bought it.